# Advantages and disadvantages of linked list/binary trees as structures for storing and searching for data

Tags: linked-list, binary-tree

I need to write up an evaluation of what the advantages and disadvantages are of linked list and binary trees as structures for storing and searching for data. But I'm a little bit lost on what the advantages and disadvantages could be?

Any help would you greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets think of how a linked list works vs how a binary tree works
For a doubly linked list we have elements like

```
Head < - > 5 < - > 10 < - > 4 < - > tail
```

If we want to add an element we can easily add it to the head or tail of the list by pointing our new element at the end point and the value that the endpoint points to and then updating both of those to point to the new element (making sure to correctly assign previous and next) I've glossed over it here but there are lots of good resources available if you search insertion into linked list. This operation has O(1) time complexity. Do some research on insertion into (balanced) binary trees this will take much longer

Now what about searching? In the linked list above if i want to find an element i have to walk through the entire list from one side until i hit the value i want. This leads to O(n) time complexity, however if we have a balanced binary tree we can check if what we are looking for is higher or lower than the value that is ~ in the middle. If its higher we can eleminate the lower half of the numbers. Then we can do the same step with the remaining numbers. This cuts the amount of remaining numbers by ~ half at every step and leads to significantly reduced times.

There are many many ways to evaluate this and they depend on different implementations. My advice to you is to choose which implementation of each you want to focus on compare the time complexity of operations and then consider alternative implementations and what they do to the time complexity of operations.

For binary consider balanced and unbalanced.
For linked list look at doubly linked, singly linked, with and without pointers to tail (essentially stack vs queue)

If you have questions about specific implementations and how they compare let us know and we will do our best to clear that up.